# close application in IOS

Tags: ios, background, terminate

I have an in-app subscription product.  When the app is loaded, I present a "subscribe now" screen to initiate the buy process.  If the user cancels, the application MUST close/move to background/terminate since they have refused the service.  What is the best method to use to do this?

Comment: I hope this isn't a public app. One quick way is you could force one of the closing app delegate methods to run.

Comment: You are not allowed to crash your app just because they didn't subscribe to your service. This WILL get rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This situation is addressed in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, under "[Don't Quit Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)":

> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two choices.
>
> Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a correction. A screen provides feedback that reassures users that there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control, letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and continue using your application or press the Home button and open a different application

For example, consider the iTunes Store or App Store apps, which are useless without a network connection. If you put your device in Airplane Mode and then launch either one, they will display a large Wi-Fi icon with a message saying an Internet connection is required. (I think an alert offers to disable Airplane Mode, but if you tap Cancel you'll see what I mean; the app will not quit.)

Be assured, if you simply force-quit the app, Apple will reject it.

Comment: I agree. You could just put them a screen with a random image. I remember a cheap clone of the iphone having this kind of image of the devs fishing.

Comment: I am willing to leave the subscribe now screen up and let the user exit, if that seems acceptable.  Nothing will happen until they exit.  Any experience with that?

Comment: @MonicaRoseMartino No personal experience but that seems like it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's allowed.. but you can use

```
Exit(0);
```

OR:

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit];
```

The application will close.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to do that. You could just display another screen after they hit cancel explaining why they can't continue and give them a button to try again.